# How to decrypt encrypted <path:pk> and pass it to functions at generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I want to pass encrypted ids of object in Response, therefore I used AES. now I want accept the encrypted pk which is a path 'xx/xxxx/xxxx', and decrypt it first thing in the view.

`

```
import base64, re
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from django.conf import settings

import codecs

# make utf8mb4 recognizable.
codecs.register(lambda name: codecs.lookup('utf8') if name == 'utf8mb4' else None)


class AESCipher:

    def __init__(self, key, blk_sz):
        self.key = key
        self.blk_sz = blk_sz

    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        # raw is the main value
        if raw is None or len(raw) == 0:
            raise NameError("No value given to encrypt")
        raw = raw + '\0' * (self.blk_sz - len(raw) % self.blk_sz)
        raw = raw.encode('utf8mb4')
        # Initialization vector to avoid same encrypt for same strings.
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key.encode('utf8mb4'), AES.MODE_CFB, iv )
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ).decode('utf8mb4')

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        # enc is the encrypted value
        if enc is None or len(enc) == 0:
            raise NameError("No value given to decrypt")
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        # AES.MODE_CFB that allows bigger length or latin values
        cipher = AES.new(self.key.encode('utf8mb4'), AES.MODE_CFB, iv )
        return re.sub(b'\x00*$', b'', cipher.decrypt( enc[16:])).decode('utf8mb4')
```

`

I tried to accept path:pk in the url and decrypt that pk in the get_queryset() but the response of any function is that the object not found
`

```
path('<path:pk>/detail/',ProductDetailUpdateDelete.as_view(),name='product-detail'),
```

`and override the get_queryset`

class ProductDetailUpdateDelete(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

```
serializer_class=ProductSerializer
   
def get_queryset(self):
    pk = aes.decrypt(str(self.kwargs['pk']))
    product=Product.objects.filter(pk=int(pk))
    return product
```

`

this returns the object and I can access all the information, but all the operations (GET,PUT,DEL) return not found. so how can I pass the object id to the functions and I want a way to decrypt the pk beofre invoking any function in order to pass pk without overriding every function

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding get_object base function.

```
def get_object(self):
    pk = aes.decrypt(str(self.kwargs['pk']))
    product=Product.objects.filter(pk=int(pk))
    return product.first()
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is overriding the get_object method, but the problem with

```
def get_object(self):
    pk = aes.decrypt(str(self.kwargs['pk']))
    product=Product.objects.filter(pk=int(pk))
    return product
```

this it returns the right object but with type: <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>, and to be able to access object attributes we need the returned object to be of type: <class 'products_app.models.Product'>. But the returned QuerySet contains only one object which is the desired object, therefore I used this to solve my problem

```
def get_object(self):
    pk = aes.decrypt(str(self.kwargs['pk']))
    product=Product.objects.filter(pk=int(pk))
    return product[0]
```